# Apply the file's audio effects

Tags: ffmpeg, android, voice-command

I'm new to ffmpeg, as the title says, I want to apply effects to audio files, like this app

[https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.baviux .voicechanger]

How can I determine the value of the effects to use on the audio file, is there any sample or not? Thank you everyone for reading

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hello, this is not a good question for this website, this network is waiting for specific problems which you tried to solve first. What you're looking for is the documentation. Which you got linked to in an "answer".

Answer (score 0):

ffmpeg doesn't really have ready-to-go preconfigured audio effects to be applied on audio the way this app does.
Instead, it utilizes an in-built audio library to provide a wide range of audio filters.
By experimenting with a combination of filters and their settings, you would be most likely able to mimic most of the stuff the app does.

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Audio-Filters

Depending on what exactly you want to do, you'll most likely have the most luck determining the "value" of an effect organoleptically.